# Difference between "=" and "match" in sqlite3, Python?

Tags: python, select, sqlite

Two similar queries:

```
firstQuery = "select * from table_name where column_name = match_value"
secondQuery = "select * from table_name where column_name match match_value"
```

executing the first one using [dbCursor.execute()](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite3#sqlite3) works fine, but executing the second one throws:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to use function MATCH in the requested context
```

Could someone please explain to me why is that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the sqlite [expression syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) docs:

> The MATCH operator is a special syntax for the match() application-defined function. *The default match() function implementation raises an exception and is not really useful for anything.* But extensions can override the match() function with more helpful logic.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.7

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("create table test(v1 text, v2 int)")

for index in range(5):
    cur.execute("insert into test values(\"python ###{index}\", {index})".format(index=index))

import re
def matchPattern(pattern, value):
    return bool(re.match(pattern, value)) # return true or false

# creating the 'match' function.
conn.create_function("matchPattern", 2, matchPattern)
```

## running...

```
i = cur.execute("select v1, v2 from test where matchPattern('python', v1)")
print i.fetchall()
```

*# print -> ["python ###1", 1), "python ###2", 2), ..., ....]*